# UIView snapshot crashes in iOS app running natively on Apple Silicon

Tags: ios, macos, snapshot, apple-m1, silicon

I am using default `snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)` in my app and it crashes on Mac Mini with M1 chip (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)

Also, I got the same crash with `drawViewHierarchyInRect` and all of this graphics/UI methods.

Any ideas what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: M1 is still a bit buggy but something like `drawViewHierarchyInRect` should work fine. It's probably something else that's causing the crash.

Comment: @aheze you are right, it works in empty app in Swift, so the problem is more specific. Maybe some obj-c bridges thing, will check later.

Comment: I'll test it out. Which simulator and Xcode version are you using?

Comment: @aheze I described, it's not in a simulator, its native iOS app on M1. Xcode 12.2

Comment: Hi @DamikMinnegalimov , did you find the cause/workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also had this crash, suspected it had something to do with using a Metal layer in our app. Couldn't figure out the exact cause, but the issue seems to be resolved in macOS Monterey.